# Validar Texfield permita solo numeros

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo la siguiente validacion.

Funciona pero en el Front me acepta estos campos.
0123456789-+.e

necesito sean solo numeros y el backspace.
Tengo estas 2 opciones por el momento.

Cualquier apoyo para resolverlo.
Saludos comunidad.

````
onKeyPress={function (e) {
var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode
return (key >= 48 && key <= 57)
}}

```
onKeyDown={function (e) {
                              if( 
                                  e.keyCode < 48 || 
                                    e.keyCode > 57 ) {
                                  e.preventDefault();
                               }
                           }}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberias usar regex para ello. Con eso compruebas que sea un numero entre 0 - 9 y el backspace que es `\b` :

```
onKeyPress={function (e) {
    var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode
    return Regex.IsMatch(key.Text, "[0-9\b]+");
}}
```